# Django form as GET

Tags: django, django-forms

I want to have my site having form validation and xml generation by using GET. There will be no form rendering as HTML to fill, simply request will be a GET that parameters are generated automatically via a software.

Here is my form:

```
from django import forms
class xmlRetrievalForm(forms.Form):
    selected_date = forms.DateField(input_formats=['%d/%m/%Y',], error_messages={'required': 'selected_date is required (ie: 29/11/2011)', 'invalid': 'selected_date field is required (ie: 29/11/2011)'})
    start_time = forms.TimeField(error_messages={'required': 'start time is required (ie: 13:11)', 'invalid': 'start_time field is required (ie: 13:11)'})
    end_time = forms.TimeField(error_messages={'required': 'end time is required (ie: 13:11)', 'invalid': 'end_time field is required (ie: 13:11)'})
    channel_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30, error_messages={'required': 'channel_name 
field is required', 'invalid': 'enter a valid channel_name.'})
```

Now instead of POST, I need to receive form data as GET parameters,

How can I achieve this in the view ?

Regards

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can't imagine where you are having trouble. Simply replace `request.POST` with `request.GET` when you instantiate the form.

Comment: thanks! all the tutorials were about POST thus I thought it was rather hairy.

Comment: Make sure you also change method="post" to method="get" in your html template's <form> section.

Comment: Forms aren't manually instantiate when using `FormView`s (which is the most common).