# Enable browser to go back to page with filters

Tags: javascript, python, django, python-2.7, django-views

I have a website like this:

```
http://google.com
```

On the page there's a search box and some filters, which when we do search the URL will become:

```
http://google.com/?search=Stuff&type=Books
```

On the results page there will be books that we can click on, which will take us into a URL like this:

```
http://google.com/book_info/harry-potter
```

I want to put a back button that will take the user back to the search page, but with the filters etc already selected so they can continue on. This works if they access the book info directly from the same tab as the search (so they access the search with filters, then click on the book), but if they access the book by opening a new tab, I can't just simply have javascript redirect the user back 1 page in their history.

Is there a way for me to do this?

Thanks :)

Comment: This might be a case for localStorage. Depending on the use case you may want to consider storing this on the server - like in the session object if you're using it.

Answer (score 0):

I would say for the best user experience you should allow using the built into every browser back button. Your forms with filtersd would need then to send GET instead of POST ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5430916/django-form-as-get)), and your views will have to [accept arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6492952/how-can-i-pass-optional-arguments-in-django-view) based on which you can apply filters.

Take a look on `django.contrib.admin`, they have something similar.

If you are insistent on the custom "back" button you could write a [middleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/middleware/) that remembers last N pages user has visited, and save it into the [session](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/sessions/). It wouldn't work well with multiple tabs though.